# Present Tense and Past Tense In the Same Sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, past-tense, present-tense

Is there anything wrong with this phase: "I had to get my hair cut last week, since it was getting too long."

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where’s the present tense??